# Here-document without interpreting escape sequences, but with interpolation

Tags: quoting, variable, escape-characters, latex, here-document

Is there any way to cat a file without interpreting the double backslash as an escape sequence?

In this example a tex file is created:

```
cat <<EOF > file.tex
\\documentclass[varwidth=true,border=5pt]{standalone}
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\usepackage{amsmath}

\\begin{document}
$1
\\end{document}
EOF
```

How can I write this so that the backslash doesn't have to be written twice each time, but `$1` is still expanded with its normal value (which might contain backslashes too)?

Comment: `cat <<'EOF'`; looking for duplicate...

Comment: @MichaelHomer in this particular example, escape characters are not interpreted, but so it is `$1`, and the bash parameter is not expanded as desired.

Comment: You want `$1` expanded, but `\ ` ignored? I think you're out of luck, at least with any straightforward approach. The shell's never going to have variable interpolation enabled without a way to escape it.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you want to happen, and what you want not to happen.

Comment: @MichaelHomer questions updated. Yes, that's exactly what I need, to cat LaTeX code into a file, without interpreting it (but expanding the parameter). Any other non-cat-based solution?

Comment: Since this is code you use in a script, write the code the way you want (that is, using only one backslash) then use `sed` on the script to escape only the backslashes used inside the heredoc and then execute your script e.g. `sed -i ''/EOF/,/EOF/{s/\\/&&/g}' script.sh` then `./script.sh 'param\\with\backslashes'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are out of luck. The manual states:

> and \ **must** be used to quote the characters \, $, and `

There is a workaround, use several here-docs:

```
cat <<\EOF > file.tex
\documentclass[varwidth=true,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
EOF
cat <<EOF >> file.tex
$1
EOF
cat <<\EOF >> file.tex
\end{document}
EOF
```

Or better, once a variable contains a backlash, it is not changed on expansion:

```
doc1='\documentclass[varwidth=true,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
'
doc2="$1"
doc3='\end{document}
'
cat <<EOF > file.tex
$doc1
$doc2
$doc3
EOF
```

Which is a convoluted way of writing:

```
doc='\documentclass[varwidth=true,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
'"$1"'
\end{document}
'
printf '%s' "$doc" > file.tex
```

---

This also work with some other examples:

```
$ doc='\[\begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24} \\ t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34} \end{bmatrix}\]'

$ printf '%s\n' "$doc"
\[\begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24} \\ t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34} \end{bmatrix}\]'
```

And also, just to show that variables are expanded only **once**:

```
$ cat <<EOF
$doc
EOF
\[\begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24} \\ t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34} \end{bmatrix}\]
```

Comment: But what to do when a \ and $1 are on the same line?

Comment: I've tried the last solution with `\[\begin{bmatrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14} \\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} & t_{24} \\
t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} & t_{34}
\end{bmatrix}\]'` as the value of the parameter and it replaces \\  by \ , the rest of the escape characters look fine in the output file.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Then do the change of quoting characters on the one line: 'This is '"$1"' one line of '"$2"' code'

Comment: @nightcod3r I tried with your string with single quotes and it does work correctly. Please do use single quotes ' for the part that you need to avoid expansion. See my edits on the answer.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't using single quotes. Now it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat << \EOF > file.tex`.  There will be no parameter expansions or escapes parsed in the heredoc.

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
cat << \EOF
testing
\testing
\\testing
EOF
$ ./t.sh
testing
\testing
\\testing
```

Comment: I am curious as to the reasoning behind the unexplained downvote.

Comment: I have no idea, but look at my comment above: "in this particular example, escape characters are not interpreted, but so it is $1, and the bash parameter is not expanded as desired."